# Is it possible to execute SIMD comparison instruction in Java8?

Tags: java, java-8, simd

In Java8, a few kind of SIMD instructions can be executed as this article http://prestodb.rocks/code/simd/ says.

I'm wondering if an SIMD comparison instruction can be executed in Java8.

I want to check the equality of two chars (UTF-16, 16 bits number) and get the value of 0xffff if they are same and 0x0 if not in fast way. I have a large char array and I want to execute the above equality check between each char element and a particular char such as 0x0022 by looping the array.

Is it possible to execute SIMD comparison instruction in Java8? Or is there any bitwise manipulation or algorithm which can execute char comparison efficiently and fast?

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to follow the methodology described in the post: write the code and benchmark. But there isn't a way to tell the JIT to use a specific CPU instruction. Also note that comparing two characters is probably a single instruction already. Have you checked the assembly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and advice.

I checked the performance of characters comparing operation, but unfortunately, the performance of the code like `(values[i] == 0x0022) ? 0xffff : 0x0` under the "-XX:+UseSuperWord" option is same as the one under the "-XX:-UseSuperWord".

I think SIMD will not be executed when I use `if` so I need to execute comparison without `if` (only using bitwise operation).

Comment: You can make it branch-free using `(char)((c-0x23)>>31&(0x21-c)>>31)` (where `c` is your current `char` value), but whether this still is simple enough to be vectorized, I don’t know…

Comment: @Holger Thanks you very much for your advice.  I will check the performance of your solution.

Comment: Umm... Holger's code was not executed in vectorized mode. Type cast from char to int seems to prevent the vectorized execution.

Comment: @bluesun how do you see that? vectorization as far as I can tell would be an intrinsic call that JIT has to take care of

Comment: The article you found already contains the answer to your question: *"As of Java 8, there is no way to use SIMD intrinsics in Java directly as can be done in C++ or C#, for example. … However, Java can also generate SIMD code under some conditions. If it detects that subsequent iterations of a loop perform independent calculations, Java can try to vectorize such loop."*

Comment: @assylias you *could* implement your own intrinsics, I've seen people do that with custom JVM's

Comment: @bluesun: there is no type cast from `char` to `int`, as that would be a no-op. There is a cast from `int` to `char`, which is just a shorter equivalent to `intValue & 0xffff`, which shouldn’t challenge optimizers. But if that’s the problem, well, you may replace `(char)(…)` with `(…)&0xffff` and try…

Answer (score 7):

Arrays equality is vectorized in `jdk-9` (when possible as fas as I can tell), according to [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143355)

Even the method internally has a definition as :

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
static int vectorizedMismatch...
```

But this is not ported to jdk-8.

As far as bitwise manipulation goes, *lots* of operations are already intrensified; as denoted by the `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation.

Your best bet it to actually test with with a few options like:

```
 -XX:-TieredCompilation 
 -XX:CICompilerCount=1
 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
 -XX:+PrintCompilation 
 -XX:+PrintInlining
```

And check if you have entries like this: `Unsafe::getAndAddInt (27 bytes)   (intrinsic)`.

And the last obvious point probably is what is your target of speed here? Even if you don't get intrinsics where you actually might think you want, the speed could be in the range where you want it to be.